# How to make a parquet file from scala case class using AvroParquetWriter?

Tags: scala, avro, parquet

I have a case class like below:

```
case class Person(id:Int,name: String)
```

Now, i wrote the below method to make a parquet file from a **Seq[T]** using **AvroParquetWriter**.

```
  def writeToFile[T](data: Iterable[T], schema: Schema, path: String, accessKey: String, secretKey: String): Unit = {
    val conf = new Configuration

    conf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", accessKey)
    conf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", secretKey)

    val s3Path = new Path(path)
    val writer = AvroParquetWriter.builder[T](s3Path)
      .withConf(conf)
      .withSchema(schema)
      .withWriteMode(ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE)
      .build()
      .asInstanceOf[ParquetWriter[T]]

    data.foreach(writer.write)

    writer.close()
  }
```

The schema is:

```
val schema = SchemaBuilder
    .record("Person")
      .fields()
      .requiredInt("id")
      .requiredString("name")
      .endRecord()
```

Now, when i call writeToFile with below code, i got exception:

```
val personData = Seq(Person(1,"A"),Person(2,"B"))

ParquetService.writeToFile[Person](
      data = personData,
      schema = schema,
      path = s3Path,
      accessKey = accessKey,
      secretKey = secretKey
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException:com.entities.Person cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord

Why **Person** can not be casted to **IndexedRecord**? Is there anything extra i need to do to get rid of this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and according to this example

https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/f84938441be49c665595c936ac631c3e5f171bf9/parquet-avro/src/test/java/org/apache/parquet/avro/TestReflectReadWrite.java#L141

you are missing one method call on writer builder.

```
val writer = AvroParquetWriter.builder[T](s3Path)
  .withConf(conf)
  .withSchema(schema)
  .withDataModel(ReflectData.get) //This one
  .withWriteMode(ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE)
  .build()
```

Also, if you wish to support nulls in your data, you can use `ReflectData.AllowNull.get()`